# Trying to access dynamically generated input fields and compare it to comforming length .json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm writing some code where I've dynamically generated html input fields via a for loop that conforms to the length of some data in a .json file.  I'd like to make it so that when someone types text into the input field, jquery will scan through the particular .json category that the input fields are equal to the length of, in an effort to compare the two to see if there are any matches.  It seemed like a simple enough thing to do, but I've run into some problems.  I'm basically trying to just access the dynamically created html via the loop and extract whatever the user types in and compare it to the .json data.  If anybody has any helpful ideas I'd appreciate it.  thank you.

My .js file looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('rote.json', function(data){
    var rand = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    var randCat = rand.cat;
    var randMem = rand.members;
    var randMemL = randMem.length;
    $("h2").html(randCat);

var output = '';

for (var i=0;i<randMemL;i++){ 
    output += '<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write your tag here" /><br>';
}

$('.fields').html(output);

$('.input').keyup(function(){

//...what now?

    });
});
```

});

my .json file looks like this:

```
[
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'A'",
  "members": [
      "a",
      "abbr",
      "address",
      "article",
      "area",
      "aside",
      "audio"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'B'",
  "members": [
      "base",
      "bdo",
      "blockquote",
      "body",
      "br",
      "base",
      "base"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'C'",
  "members": [
      "canvas",
      "caption",
      "cite",
      "col",
      "colgroup",
      "canvas"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'D'",
  "members": [
      "dd",
      "del",
      "div",
      "dl",
      "dt"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'E'",
  "members": [
      "em",
      "embed"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'F'",
  "members": [
      "fieldset",
      "figcaption",
      "figure",
      "footer",
      "form"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'G'",
  "members": [
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'H'",
  "members": [
      "h1",
      "h2",
      "h3",
      "h4",
      "h5",
      "h6",
      "head",
      "header",
      "hgroup",
      "hr",
      "html"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'I'",
  "members": [
      "i",
      "iframe",
      "img",
      "input",
      "ins"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'J'",
  "members": [
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'K'",
  "members": [
      "kbd"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'L'",
  "members": [
      "label",
      "legend",
      "li",
      "link"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'M'",
  "members": [
      "map",
      "mark",
      "meta"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'N'",
  "members": [
      "nav",
      "noscript"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'O'",
  "members": [
      "object",
      "ol",
      "optgroup",
      "option"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'P'",
  "members": [
      "p",
      "param",
      "pre",
      "progress"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'Q'",
  "members": [
      "q"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'R'",
  "members": [
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'S'",
  "members": [
      "s",
      "samp",
      "script",
      "section",
      "select",
      "small",
      "source",
      "span",
      "style",
      "strong",
      "sub",
      "summary",
      "sup"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'T'",
  "members": [
      "table",
      "tbody",
      "td",
      "textarea",
      "tfoot",
      "th",
      "thead",
      "time",
      "title",
      "tr",
      "track"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'U'",
  "members": [
      "u",
      "ul"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'V'",
  "members": [
      "var",
      "video"
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'W'",
  "members": [
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'X'",
  "members": [
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'Y'",
  "members": [
    ]
},
{ "cat": "List all html tags that begin with the letter 'Z'",
  "members": [
    ]
}
```

]

the HTML is pretty simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <title>Rote-App</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
      <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="rote.css"> -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="searcharea">
<h2></h2>
<div class="fields"></div>
</div>
<div id="update"></div>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rote.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex), this could be a start :

```
$('.input').keyup(function () {

    var answer = this.value,
        index = _.findIndex(randMem, function (tag) {
            return answer == tag;
        });
    console.log(index);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do but here is a solution.

replace for loop

```
for (var i=0;i<randMemL;i++){ 
output = $('<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write your tag here"/>');
output.data('tags', randMem);
$('.fields').append(output);
```

}

add this to event

```
$('.input').keyup(function(){
var answer = $(this).val();
var tags = $(this).data('tags')
if(tags.indexOf(answer) != -1)
    $(this).css('border-color','green');
else 
    $(this).css('border-color','red');


});
```

Or Just go to this fiddle ! http://jsfiddle.net/66nrj3sy/